# What is the age of Budarsinghi Temple?

Tags: ancient-history, india

There is a small Hanuman temple about 30 kilometers south of [Hubli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubli) in my home state of Karnataka in India. Below is the image of Lord Hanuman's idol. The idol certainly looks quite old, but the folks here say that it was constructed by none other than [Janmejaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janamejaya) himself, the grandson of Arjuna of Mahabharat fame.

Can someone verify if this temple is really that old?

[image: picture of Hanuman's idol]

Comment: Are you asking whether the actual building is ancient, whether the idol is ancient, or whether a temple has been in that location for the last 5,000 years?

Comment: @twosheds I just want to verify the authenticity of what the local folks say. If the idol really belonged to that era (irrespective of whether it was relocated or not), it would gain a great historical importance because hardly anything exists that old anywhere in India.

Comment: fwiw, here's a [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=qxxSQtJS-ac) of the temple. The building itself clearly isn't ancient, though I can't speak to when any of the idols were created.